# Removing the /folder/ from Wordpress using mod rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, url

I'm working on a blog installed in its own sub folder so the URL for an article looks like this:

I need it to just look like this:

http://www.sampleurl.com/article

I'm not able to install it on the root directory so would a mod rewrite be able to do this and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Over in the WordPress support forums we refer folks to this article for that: [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).  Hope it helps you out.

Comment: +1 For pointing out that Wordpress has its own support forum.